# MongoDB aggregate merge and retrieve

Tags: mongodb

After running an aggregate / merge query is there a way to also determine if a record was inserted without having to run a second query?

After running this aggregate, how do I know if a new record was inserted or not?

```
connection.collection('settings').aggregate( [
   { $match : { group_id: 2 } },
   { $project: {level: 1, group:1} },
   { $addFields:{item_id: 2} },
   { $merge : 'items', on: ['group_id', 'item_id'] }
])
```

**There are two instances when a record would not be inserted**

1. a duplicate exists based on the index group_id, item_id
2. if there are no matching record in settings when doing the match

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: I see thank you. Somewhat related, is there a reason my aggregate doesn't seem to run unless I add .toArray() at the end. Is that normal behavior? It seems the handler to toArray returns empty data either way.

Comment: Some of the operations in drivers are lazy, notably queries. In case of $out/$merge, these stages essentially are write operations but they are implemented through a read operation API (aggregation pipeline) so you still need to trigger pipeline evaluation.

Comment: For example, see https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-aggregation/#the-aggregation-pipeline the allow disk use examples for one case where you would modify the pipeline after defining the stages but before executing.